# Use IF condition in Python to Import Data from SQL Table (or Import Data from SQL table only when condition satisfies in Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a **condition to check in Python**.
If the condition satisfies, only then I have to go ahead and **extract data from a table in my SQL database.**

The below code is working perfectly and giving me the extracted data from the SQL database.

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXXXXX', 
            password='XXXXXXX',host='XXXXXXX',database='XXXXXXX')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table where table.column = 'abc')
result = cursor.fetchall()
print (result)
conn.close()
```

Now, I am trying to use an **IF Condition** before fetching data from SQL database.
But this gives me **syntax error**.

Please find a sample of what I am trying as mentioned below:

```
if(x == 'True'):
    (import mysql.connector
     conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXXXXX', 
            password='XXXXXXX',host='XXXXXXX',database='XXXXXXX')
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table where table.column = 'abc')
     result = cursor.fetchall()
     print (result)
     conn.close())
else:
    print("X is false, cannot execute")
```

**Please help how can I execute only with a condition satisfied.**

Comment: Try removing the bracket before the `import` keyword

Answer (score 1):

1. You should remove parenthesis in **if** block. Such a parenthesis you should use only when you call methods in chain, for example:

```
mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXXXXX', password='XXXXXXX',host='XXXXXXX',database='XXXXXXX')

(
    mysql.
    connector.
    connect(user='XXXXXXX', password='XXXXXXX',host='XXXXXXX',database='XXXXXXX')
)
```

2. If **x** condition returns Boolean output True/False, enough is:

```
if x:
    ....
else:
    ....
```

3. If **x** condition returns Boolean output True/False, True is not equal 'True':

```
True == 'True'

# output
False
```

Comment: Thank you. Removing the <brackets> worked. Also, there was indentation to be done post <brackets> removal. Code is working now.